# Stored Procedure Oracle (expression 'TO_NUMBER(SQLDEVBIND1Z_1)' cannot be used as an assignment target)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

We've started to learn about stored procedures in class the other week, professor already gave a big assignment that is very complicated, and at this point I'm very confused. I'm not even sure what exactly am I trying to accomplish here.

I need to create a procedure for the following select statement

```
SELECT * 

FROM Vehicle, VAN 

WHERE SEATCAPACITY > 5 

AND MAXIMUMPAYLOAD > 5000;
```

This is what I have compiled and stored procedure was compiled successfully.

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE GET_VAN_SP
 (
          van_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
       )  AS
     BEGIN OPEN van_cursor for

     SELECT Vehicle.VINNUMBER VINNUMBER,
     Vehicle.MAKE MAKE,
     Vehicle.MODELKIND MODELKIND,
     Vehicle.YEARMADE YEARMADE,
     Vehicle.RENTALCATEGORYID RENTALCATEGORYID,
     Vehicle.COLOR COLOR,
     Vehicle.PLATENUMBER PLATENUMBER,
     Vehicle.MILEAGE MILEAGE,
     Vehicle.TRANSMISIONTYPE TRANSMISIONTYPE,
     Vehicle.SEATCAPACITY SEATCAPACITY,
     Vehicle.DAILYRENTALCOST DAILYRENTALCOST,
     Vehicle.VEHICLESTATUSID VEHICLESTATUSID,
     Vehicle.ASSIGNEDAGENCYID ASSIGNEDAGENCYID,
     Vehicle.CURRENTAGENCYID CURRENTAGENCYID,
     Vehicle.VEHICLETYPE VEHICLETYPE,
     Vehicle.PRICE PRICE,
     Vehicle.MPH MPH,
     Vehicle.HORSEPOWER HORSEPOWER,
     Vehicle.MPG MPG,
     VAN.VVINNUMBER VVINNUMBER,
     VAN.CARGOCAPACITY CARGOCAPACITY,
     VAN.MAXIMUMPAYLOAD MAXIMUMPAYLOAD 
     FROM Vehicle, VAN 
     WHERE SEATCAPACITY > 5 
     AND MAXIMUMPAYLOAD > 5000; 

     END GET_VAN_SP;
```

This is the error while attempting to execute.

> Error starting at line : 37 in command -
>           BEGIN  GET_VAN_SP(5); END;
>           Error report -
>           ORA-06550: line 1, column 52:
>           PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_VAN_SP'
>           ORA-06550: line 1, column 63:
>           PLS-00363: expression 'TO_NUMBER(SQLDEVBIND1Z_1)' cannot be used as an 
>           assignment target
>           ORA-06550: line 1, column 52:
>           PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>           06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>           *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>           *Action:

Comment: Is this for SQL-Server or Oracle? They are two different RDBMS.

Comment: Why are you having a refcursor as an out parameter of your procedure?

Comment: oracle and the problem is when I'm trying to execute the procedure.

Comment: Professor wants us to use cursor, unless I misunderstood something

Answer (score 1):

This:

> I'm not even sure what exactly am I trying to accomplish here

is the biggest problem of all. In my opinion, you should re-read the assignment as many times as necessary, until you know exactly what you should do. If you can't make it, you should consult the professor. *How* to do that job is another problem.

OK, to get you started, here are two procedures that use the same `SELECT` statement as source of data. It is based on Scott's schema (as I don't have your tables, and you didn't provide test case).

The first procedure accepts two `IN` parameters - department number and salary (which is similar to what you are doing). Note that I'm joining two tables, which is what you did not do (but should have): there are two tables in your query, VEHICLE and VAN - without join, you'll get Cartesian product.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2    (par_deptno in dept.deptno%type,
  3     par_sal    in emp.sal%type
  4    )
  5  is
  6  begin
  7    for cur_r in (select d.dname, e.ename, e.sal
  8                  from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  9                  where d.deptno = par_deptno
 10                    and e.sal > par_sal
 11                 )
 12    loop
 13      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.dname ||' '|| cur_r.ename ||' '|| cur_r.sal);
 14    end loop;
 15  end;
 16  /

Procedure created.

SQL> begin
  2    p_test(10, 2000);
  3  end;
  4  /
ACCOUNTING KING 5000
ACCOUNTING CLARK 2450

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

The second one uses `refcursor` (as in your example - I'm not sure whether that's what you really need to do, because YOU don't know it either). Your procedure expects one `OUT` parameter (a `refcursor`), but you're passing an `IN` parameter, a `NUMBER` (5). Doesn't make much sense, does it? Note that I'm passing two `IN` and one `OUT` parameter, which is what Oracle expects.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2    (par_deptno in dept.deptno%type,
  3     par_sal    in emp.sal%type,
  4     par_out    out sys_refcursor
  5    )
  6  is
  7  begin
  8    open par_out for
  9      select d.dname, e.ename, e.sal
 10      from dept d join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
 11      where d.deptno = par_deptno
 12        and e.sal > par_sal;
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.

SQL> var l_out refcursor
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    p_test(10, 2000, :l_out);
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print l_out

DNAME          ENAME             SAL
-------------- ---------- ----------
ACCOUNTING     KING             5000
ACCOUNTING     CLARK            2450

SQL>
```

I hope it'll help; try to apply such a code to your case. Say if you can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is an integer passed to the procedure GET_VAN_SP when it expects a
>   parameter of type SYS_REFCURSOR?

Comment: what would that parameter be?